# find the failing element in `any` function

Tags: python

Is there a way to know which element has failed the `any` built-in function?

I was trying to solve [Euler 5](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5) and I want to find for which numbers my product isn't evenly divisible. Using the for loop it's easy to figure it out, but is it possible with `any` also?

```
from operator import mul

primes_under_20 = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
product = reduce(mul, primes_under_20, 1)

if any((product % i != 0 for i in range(1,21))):
    print "not evenly divisible"
# how can I find out that 4 was the element that failed?
# must I use this for loop?

for i in range(1,21):
    if product % i != 0:
        print i # prints 4
        break
```

I read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) that `any` is equivalent to:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

but is this the exact implementation, or is there a hiding `yield` there, or something like this that can help lock on the element?

Comment: There is no need for a yield, since both any() and all() use iterators but do not return an iterator but a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any good reason to use `any`?
If you want an one-liner to find out which numbers are not evenly divisible :

```
not_divisible = [i for i in range(1, 21) if product % i != 0]  
if len(not_divisible) > 0:
    print(not_divisible)
```

You can't really get all the non-divisible numbers with `any`, since it stops when it finds the first `False` in the iterable

Comment: @CIsForCookies. In that case: `next(i for i in range(1, 21) if product % i != 0)`.

Comment: Well... I did get all the numbers in one line. If you really need that feature then go ahead and use @glibdud answer. Be aware that what (s)he's doing there uses a **really** deprecated aspect of python which does not work with python 3. So please stop thinking that using `any` is justified

Comment: @Fred. Totally agree that `any` is the wrong tool for the job. And I don't see much wrong with your answer, since there is nothing special about the first non-divisor.

Comment: Disregard my last comment. Didn't read @glibdud answer properly :)

Comment: Sorry, was too tired when I first looked at your answer. I agree that `any` is not doing what I want, and this one-liner / for loop would be better. I just hoped that `any` might have a hidden feature allowing to use it in a way to suit my needs (and therefore be better than the other options)

Answer (score 1):

I probably wouldn't recommend actually doing this, as it feels a bit hacky (and uglier than just scrapping the `any()` for a `for` loop). That disclaimer aside, this could technically be accomplished by exploiting an iterator and `any()`'s property of stopping once it's found a truthy value:

```
rangemax = 21
rng = iter(range(1,rangemax))
if any(product % i != 0 for i in rng):
    print "not evenly divisible"
    try:
        print next(rng) - 1
    except StopIteration:
        print rangemax - 1
```

This creates an iterator based on the `range()`, then runs `any()`, and if it evaluates `True`, you check the next item in the iterator (or the max number if you're at the end of the iterator) and subtract one.

Comment: Should include in the answer that this is in no way translatable to python 3. List comprehension leaking was fixed

Comment: @Fred Eh? Works fine for me in 3.6 (with appropriate edits to the `print`s and adding the import for `reduce()`). I'm not exploiting the comprehension, I'm exploiting the iterator that's defined external to it.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you were using the leaked `i` for a moment there. My mistake for not reading it till the end. My apologies. Here's an upvote